# how to work more than one button in a asp form

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have more than one buttons in a form. if i click the first button. a text box will be created. while click on the second button the page will refresh and the text box will be gone.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Check the button click event bind with both button & place some code.

Comment: You need recreate dynamically created controls on every postback.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you dynamically create the textbox when the first button is clicked, you need to create that textbox on every postback.

Instead, why not keep the textbox permanently on the page, but have it set invisible. When the first button is clicked, make the textbox visible. Save the visibility state in Session state.

Comment: +1. the visibile property is saved automatically in the viewstate. So if you are mainly working with postbacks, the visibility will be stored the whole time. If you are leaving this page through a GET, you will have to save it somewhere else, like in the Session State as @john described.

Comment: @Luke: 3:20am here and "why am I still awake?"

Comment: because of the addictive SO i think

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem very easily.
this is a page  post back problem when you click on the page then you page will be post back and again reload. so the first button code you can write in if condition
like:

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
// WRITE CODE HERE FOR FIRST BUTTON
}
```